# "with... as" in SQL Navigator

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query works:

```
select count(*) from everything where num not in (select num from sometable)
```

The following query is supposed to be equivalent to the above, but results in an "invalid identifier" error:

```
with unwanted as (select num from sometable)
select count(*) from everything where num not in unwanted
```

What is wrong with the second query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the syntax is like this:

```
with unwanted as (select num from sometable)
select count(*) from everything where num not in (select * from unwanted)
```

obviously this makes only sense if the `select num from sometable` part is a bit more complex or used several times later...

Comment: I accepted your answer. Still, can you please add an explanation to why `select * from unwanted` is not the same as `unwanted`? Thanks.

Comment: The with-clause can be seen equivalent with a view or a table except for the fact that it is defined dynamically at run-time and isn't defined static as view or table. Usage and syntax in your sql is always the same and the name of with-clause, table, and view can be used interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

You can also join the tables for faster performance

```
WITH unwanted
AS
(
    SELECT  num 
    FROM    sometable
)
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    everything a
        LEFT JOIN unwanted b
            ON a.num = b.num
WHERE   b.num IS NULL
```